# "Could not initialize class com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.decorator.AndroidPluginDslDecoratorKt" Error in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have just created a new project and worked with it for about a day. I even ran it many times before but I don't know why I get this error:

> Could not initialize class com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.decorator.AndroidPluginDslDecoratorKt

Would really appreciate some help regarding it. Besides this error I,m also getting the log sometimes:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/commons/Method

I tried changing classpaths and changing the names of plugins and methods of implementation of plugins but none of them work for me. The project neither builds, nor does it clean or rebuild.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After spending many time then finally I got solutions for this problem.

1. update dependencies in build.gradle gragle from classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0' to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:**gradle:7.4.2'**
2. update URL in gradle-wrapper.properties file distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip. to distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/**gradle-7.5-all.zip**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same issue,
What i did was changing the **classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0**
4.4.0  to  4.3.0
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0
It works now