Flutter run the flutter example got failed on Android Studio
I'm a beginner. On the first day of creating a new Flutter project, the emulator worked correctly during the build process.
However, when opening the project on the second day, the following error occurred:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Build file 'E:\android\Android Project\myflutter\android\build.gradle' line: 13

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.



Build completed with 1 failure.
Could not initialize class com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.decorator.AndroidPluginDslDecoratorKt


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Line 13 of build.gradle is project.evaluationDependsOn(":app").
update the whole code in E:\android\Android Project\myflutter\android\build.gradle
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

I googled and found that it seems I need to change the classpath, but I couldn't find where to make the change in the gradle file inside the android folder in my Flutter project.

share the whole code in E:\android\Android Project\myflutter\android\build.gradle this file here

@GoVindh I have updated it

any new dependencies added ?
or update the pubspec.yaml file

@GoVindh no, it's a new Flutter project

you can look at  this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76303390/could-not-initialize-class-com-android-build-gradle-internal-dsl-decorator-andr

@GoVindh I've read this article, but I don't know how to change the Android classpath in Flutter

@GoVindh I solved my issue. After changing the Gradle version in gradle-wrapper.properties, it worked correctly. Thank you for your help

ok Alright great
